# React Native Performance: Javascript vs Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Is Javascript or Typescript different in React Native App performance?

Which Javascript or Typescript is recommended for developing React Native application?

I hope my question wasn't too imaginative.

Comment: typescript is compiled to javascript, there is no difference.

Comment: So it doesn't affect app performance? @tkausl

Comment: As tkausl said, TypeScript needs to be compiled to JavaScript. What the client uses is the compiled JavaScript. Of course, when developing, each `.ts` script has to be compiled to its corresponding `.js`, so there is that extra compilation step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, typescript is just compiled to javascript. Think of Typescript as a tool like eslint that helps you write better code, just in a different way (forcing object types, etc). There will be no performance change to the user, only difference is in whatever step you do to build your application will now have to have a typescript parser that compiles it.